# Magento Checkout OnepageController not getting override

Tags: magento, controller, magento-1.9, checkout, onepage-checkout

I have searched and implemented many answers from stackoverflow but I am not able to override the controller. The question is quite self-explanatory but I will provide the codes to show what I am doing. Maybe someone can guide me in the right direction:

This is my [directory structure](https://prnt.sc/kjpu1m)

This is my `config.xml` inside `etc` folder.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
<modules>
    <Zepcom_Checkout>
        <version>0.0.1</version>
    </Zepcom_Checkout>
</modules>
<frontend>
    <routers>
        <checkout>
            <args>
                <modules>
                    <Zepcom_Checkout before="Mage_Checkout">Zepcom_Checkout</Zepcom_Checkout>
                </modules>
            </args>
        </checkout>
    </routers>
</frontend>
```

And this is my `controller`

```
require_once 'Mage/Checkout/controllers/OnepageController.php';


class Zepcom_Checkout_OnepageController extends Mage_Checkout_OnepageController {
      public function indexAction() {
         var_dump("custom"); die;
      }
.
.  // some overriding code here
.
}
```

I am really stuck and any help would be appreciated. I am doing a dump to verify the calling of the controller but it keeps calling the `Core` controller.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to declare a router "routeurfrontend" which is actually the route used by Magento to access your controller.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <frontend>
        <routers>
            <zepcom_checkout>
                <use>standard</use>
                <args>
                    <module>Zepcom_Checkout</module>
                    <frontName>zepcom_checkout</frontName>
                </args>
            </zepcom_checkout>
            <checkout>
                <args>
                    <modules>
                        <Zepcom_Checkout before="Mage_Checkout">Zepcom_Checkout</Zepcom_Checkout>
                    </modules>
                </args>
            </checkout>
        </routers>
    </frontend>
</config>
```

Comment: thanks, but I dont want to use my custom routing. I want to simply override the Onepagecontroller by using the default `checkout/onepage/` route

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the `</config>` closing tag in your config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Zepcom_Checkout>
            <version>0.0.1</version>
        </Zepcom_Checkout>
    </modules>
    <frontend>
        <routers>
            <checkout>
                <args>
                    <modules>
                        <Zepcom_Checkout before="Mage_Checkout">Zepcom_Checkout</Zepcom_Checkout>
                    </modules>
                </args>
            </checkout>
        </routers>
    </frontend>
</config>
```